# How to remove Eclipse Move from context menu and refactor main menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to remove move command for specific resource type. To achieve it, I thought to using `org.eclipse.ui.activities`

I tried below configuration, but it didn't work.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
      <activity
            id="refactormovehiding.id"
            name="refactormovehiding">
         <enabledWhen>
            <not>
               <instanceof
                     value="com.shashwat.resource.PResource">
               </instanceof>
            </not>
         </enabledWhen>
      </activity>
      <activityPatternBinding
            activityId="refactormovehiding.id"
            pattern=".*/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.Move">
      </activityPatternBinding>
   </extension>
```

I even used different pattern thinking pattern which I am providing is incorrect

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
      <activity
            id="refactormovehiding.id"
            name="refactormovehiding">
         <enabledWhen>
            <not>
               <instanceof
                     value="com.shashwat.resource.PResource">
               </instanceof>
            </not>
         </enabledWhen>
      </activity>
      <activityPatternBinding
            activityId="refactormovehiding.id"
            pattern=".*/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.moveResources">
      </activityPatternBinding>
   </extension>
```

I even tried without `enabledWhen` configuration, but no luck.

Comment: "Plug-in Menu Spy" says the action definition id of the move action is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.move.element`

Comment: Hi @greg-449 Thanks a lot. I used "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.move.element" earlier, but I didn't work because I was always adding ".*" before it. It was incorrect in this case